# I Use Youtube API V3 , my web page request bots request

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

I Use Youtube API V3 , my web page request bots request so my api result is `too many Request this Ip`

Bots Example :

1 `Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; DotBot/1.1; http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/dotbot, help@moz.com)`

2 `Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; AlphaBot/3.2; +http://alphaseobot.com/bot.html)`

this type many bots request my website [www.watchyoutubevideo.com](http://www.watchyoutubevideo.com)
Example bots Google,Bing,Yahoo etc bots ....

how to solve 
help me 
thank you